# how to avoid creating new session using window.open()?

Tags: session, window.open, requestdispatcher

**`window.open(url)`** is creating a new session.

Is there any way to prevent **`window.open()`** from doing the same. I heard using **servlet dispatcher** instead of `window.open()`. we can avoid making new session but i have no idea how to use the **dispatcher** in jsp or js file. All i have right now is the url in my javascript file.

Comment: are you talking about browser session or server session ?

Comment: hey anant thanks for replying. I was talking about server session.